# Determine the nth term in a series if:

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given a sequence $f$ where after the first term, the $n$th term is derived by $3+2(f_{n-1}+n)$, how do you find the $n$th term given that the first term is 3, and $f_n=671088573$? I don't know of any ways you can find the position of the term when the position is part of the derivation of the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_n=3+2(f_{n-1}+n)\qquad \text{with} \qquad f(0)=3$$ making the story short, we have
$$f_n=5\times 2^{n+1}-2 n-7$$ and the solution of $f_n=k$ is given by
$$n=-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-5\times 2^{-\frac{k+7}{2}} \log (2)\right)}{\log
   (2)}-\frac{k+7}{2}$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

For $f_n=671088573$, this gives $n=25.9999999828$ and $f_{26}=671088581$ just a bit higher.

If you cannot use Lambert function, since its argument $$x=-5\times 2^{-\frac{k+7}{2}} \log (2) $$ is very small, you can use the approximation
$$W(x)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(-x)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$.

In the practical case, since $k$ is large, we can expect $n$ to be large and you could even make a first approxiamtion neglection the $(2n+7)$ terms and get, as an estimte
$$5\times 2^{n+1}\simeq k \implies n_0=\frac{\log \left(\frac{k}{5}\right)}{\log (2)}-1$$

Now, taking logarithms, we can write the equation to be solved as
$$g(n)=n\log(2)+\log(10)-\log(k+2n+7)$$ which almost the equation of a straight line
$$g'(n)=\log (2)-\frac{2}{k+2 n+7}$$ and a better solution
$$n_1=n_0-\frac{g(n_0)}{g'(n_0)}$$ For the working case $n_0=25.9999998560$ and $n_1=25.9999999828$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the general solution of this non-homogeneous linear recurrence is $f_n =g_n + p_n$ where $g_n$ is the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence $g_n = 2 g_{n-1}$ and $p_n$ is a particular solution.  Look for a particular solution of the form $p_n = a n + b$.

But in this case the answer turns out to be that there is no such $n$.  With $f(1)=3$, I get $f(26) = 402653125 < 671088573$ and $f(27) = 805306307 > 671088573$.

Or if you meant $f(0)=3$, that produces $f(26)=671088581$: close, but not quite.  Maybe that $671088573$ came from a numerical computation that suffered from roundoff error.

Comment: I did mean the $f(0)=3$, and I got the same answer, accomplished by guessing and checking using: $$10(\frac{1-2^n}{1-2})-7$$ essentially, I found how much the growth from each term grows by, and then I used summation of a geometric series to find the same estimation. I came close at $671088623$